# " the field is not available to the running user" error when updating from a Transform record collection

Tags: httprequest, visual-flows

I have a simple flow that looks at the VIN number on a customer Trailer record, and looks up info from that VIN via the NHTSA API.  Immediately after the HTTP call I have a Transform element that maps the API response to the fields on the Trailer object.  The response can return multiple results, so it's structured as a collection.

I can use that collection to create new Trailer records with no problems (when I select to use all fields and create multiple).  When I try to *update* the record from which I retrieved the VIN, however, I run into issues.

When I loop on the record collection, I try to update the original record based on the first record in the collection.  But I receive an error that says "The flow failed to access the value for go_loop.00N8M000000vLcF because the field is not available to the running user."   This occurs regardless of whether I'm running in system or user context.

In my debugging I displayed a screen and used field components, and it displayed the results without issue.  However when I switched to using screen components with default values, that gave the same error as before.

[image: example of the popup screen]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error while trying to transform to a record collection. I changed to transforming to an apex class instead and that helped me get around it. I didn't have to do any coding either because the external service had already created apex classes to represent the various objects and sub-objects in the results of my API call. By using that instead of the record option, I was able to loop over the transformed data without hitting this error. In the below example, I mapped the "result" object from my API call to the apex class that represents *just* that same result object.

[image: option to select apex-defined object instead of record]

[image: mapping of apex-defined objects in the Transform element]